# Code executes successfully but the data is added in excel only at final iteration

Tags: java, excel, testng, jxl

I need help folks, i'm stuck at a point.

This is my code for after method

```
@AfterMethod
public void writeResult(ITestResult result) throws IOException, Exception
{
    Workbook workbk = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("D:\\Selenium Automation\\Selenium\\Framework\\Prototype\\Output\\eLogistics_Result_Latest.xls"));
    WritableWorkbook bookk = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("D:\\Selenium Automation\\Selenium\\Framework\\Prototype\\Output\\eLogistics_Result_Latest_Written.xls"),workbk);

    int methodCellColumn =findCellLocationColumn("D:\\Selenium Automation\\Selenium\\Framework\\Prototype\\Output\\eLogistics_Result_Latest.xls", methodName);
    int methodCellRow =findCellLocationRow("D:\\Selenium Automation\\Selenium\\Framework\\Prototype\\Output\\eLogistics_Result_Latest.xls", methodName);


    if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS)
    {
        System.out.println("Method-"+methodName+"- has Passed");
        writeDataInCell(methodCellColumn+3, methodCellRow,"Pass",bookk);
        System.out.println("Method Column number is-> "+(methodCellColumn+3));
        System.out.println("Method row number is-> "+methodCellRow);
    }
    else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
    {
        System.out.println("Method-"+methodName+"- has Failed");
        writeDataInCell(methodCellColumn+3, methodCellRow,"Fail",bookk);
        System.out.println("Method Column number is-> "+(methodCellColumn+3));
        System.out.println("Method row number is-> "+methodCellRow+"\n");

    }
    else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP)
    {
        System.out.println("Method-"+methodName+"- has Skipped");
        writeDataInCell(methodCellColumn+3, methodCellRow,"Skip",bookk);
        System.out.println("Method Column number is-> "+(methodCellColumn+3));
        System.out.println("Method row number is-> "+methodCellRow);

    }
    bookk.write();
    bookk.close();
    workbk.close();

}
```

Methods used for getting column number & cell number are returning correct results.
its methods are-

```
public int findCellLocationColumn(String xlPath,String runningMethod) throws Exception, IOException
    {
    Workbook workbk = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(xlPath));
    Sheet sht = workbk.getSheet(0);

    Cell requiredCell = sht.findCell(runningMethod);
    int cellColumnNumber = requiredCell.getColumn();
    workbk.close();
    return cellColumnNumber;

    }
```

&

```
public int findCellLocationRow(String xlPath,String runningMethod) throws Exception, IOException
    {
    Workbook workbk = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(xlPath));
    Sheet sht = workbk.getSheet(0);

    Cell requiredCell = sht.findCell(runningMethod);
    int cellRowNumber = requiredCell.getRow();
    workbk.close();
    return cellRowNumber;
    }
```

The method for **writeDataInCell** is-

```
    public void writeDataInCell(int col,int row,String result,WritableWorkbook book1)     throws RowsExceededException, WriteException, BiffException, IOException
    {
    WritableSheet firstSheet = book1.getSheet(0);

    Label label= new Label(col, row, result);

    firstSheet.addCell(label);

    System.out.println("writeDataInCell method executed for row-> "+row);
    }
```

I don't know whats going wrong but the data is not written in output excel file as expected The output excel looks like this-
[image]

**While the expected out put file should look like this-**[image]

The required console output looks like this-

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.44.0.0
Listening on port 32921
Static method completed
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\sha.RCOTIS\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--424717979\testng-    customsuite.xml
Execution mode is Y

Login method completed
Method-Login- has Passed
writeDataInCell method executed for row-> 1
Method Column number is-> 7
Method row number is-> 1
Execution mode is N
Method-quickProject- has Skipped
writeDataInCell method executed for row-> 2
Method Column number is-> 7
Method row number is-> 2
Execution mode is Y
Close Browser method completed
Method-closeBrowser- has Passed
writeDataInCell method executed for row-> 3
Method Column number is-> 7
Method row number is-> 3
Execution mode is N
Method-closeBrowser1- has Skipped
writeDataInCell method executed for row-> 4
Method Column number is-> 7
Method row number is-> 4
PASSED: Test("1", "Project Creation", "1.00", "Login", "Robert.Lezwijn@otis.com1", "Y")
PASSED: Test("2", "Complete Execution", "Final 1", "closeBrowser", "NA", "Y")
SKIPPED: Test("", "", "1.01", "quickProject", "NA", "N")
org.testng.SkipException: Execution mode is N
at eLogistics_Execution.Execute_Test.Test(Execute_Test.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at     org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)

SKIPPED: Test("2", "Complete Execution", "Final 1", "closeBrowser1", "NA", "N")
org.testng.SkipException: Execution mode is N
at eLogistics_Execution.Execute_Test.Test(Execute_Test.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at     org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Skips: 2
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Skips: 2
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 0 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@450b9338: 47 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@4f013415: 0 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@666e2862: 47 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@4ff561a7: 0 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@11def881: 0 ms
```

Help me find the solution guys . . .!!!

Comment: Can you post logic of calling writeResult() method. Probably you are doing mistake during the method call (writeResult()).

Comment: @hemanth I'm not calling **writeResult()** explicitly , its coupled with **@AfterMethod** so gets called after each test method

Comment: See my answer below as with your latest update with output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since everytime you are getting the sheet from book1 object, all the changes made are skipped except the last change. 
reference:

```
WritableSheet firstSheet = book1.getSheet(0);
```

What you could do is, change the return type of writeDataInCell() to WritableWorkBook and change the logic of calling area like this:

```
public WritableWorkbook writeDataInCell(int col,int row,String result,WritableWorkbook book1)     throws RowsExceededException, WriteException, BiffException, IOException
    {
    WritableSheet firstSheet = book1.getSheet(0);

    Label label= new Label(col, row, result);

    firstSheet.addCell(label);

    System.out.println("writeDataInCell method executed for row-> "+row);
return book1;
    }
```

And

```
if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS)
    {
        System.out.println("Method-"+methodName+"- has Passed");
        this.bookk = writeDataInCell(methodCellColumn+3, methodCellRow,"Pass",bookk);
        System.out.println("Method Column number is-> "+(methodCellColumn+3));
        System.out.println("Method row number is-> "+methodCellRow);
    }
    else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
    {
        System.out.println("Method-"+methodName+"- has Failed");
        this.bookk = writeDataInCell(methodCellColumn+3, methodCellRow,"Fail",bookk);
        System.out.println("Method Column number is-> "+(methodCellColumn+3));
        System.out.println("Method row number is-> "+methodCellRow+"\n");

    }
    else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP)
    {
        System.out.println("Method-"+methodName+"- has Skipped");
        this.bookk = writeDataInCell(methodCellColumn+3, methodCellRow,"Skip",bookk);
        System.out.println("Method Column number is-> "+(methodCellColumn+3));
        System.out.println("Method row number is-> "+methodCellRow);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.Though the first line of your answer appears to be correct,the method **writeDataInCell()** doesn't return anything, it just written to add data into cell.Thus the ** this.bookk = writeDataInCell(methodCellColumn+3, methodCellRow,"Pass",bookk);** won't work.Thanks to your answer,i now know what the problem actually is

Comment: Yes, you should also change the return type of writeDataInCell(). Edited answer by modifying writeDataInCell() too!

Comment: Thanks bro for the help.The problem is solved.Another problem was in **@AfterMethod** where a new writable worksheet was getting created at each iteration,    _WritableWorkbook bookk = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("D:\\Selenium Automation\\Selenium\\Framework\\Prototype\\Output\\eLogistics_Result_Latest_Written.xls"),workbk);
_     .Thus the file was overwritten each time.

Comment: Yes, with this thought i requested for calling area of "writeResult()" to find the leakage. However its resolved..cheers!